# Get neat text from a BeautifulSoup page

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm doing a web scraper to find job description from an URL, here's my code as of now:

```
def getJobDesc(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
        page = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
        jd = page.find("div", {"data-automation": "jobDescription"})
        return jd
    except:
        return ""
```

So it does what it's supposed to, and `jd` from a test URL is as follow:

```
<div class="vDEj0_0" data-automation="jobDescription"><span class="FYwKg _2Bz3E C6ZIU_0 _6ufcS_0 _2DNlq_0 _29m7__0"><div class="FYwKg"><p><strong>Job Responsibilities:</strong></p><ul><li><span style="color:black">Provide innovative solutions to complex business problems</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Plan, develop and implement large-scale projects from conception to completion</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Develop and architect lifecycle of projects working on different technologies and platforms</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Design, develop and implement new integration</span></li></ul><p><strong>Job Requirements:</strong></p><ul><li><span style="color:black">Proficient in Java and preferably in Python as well</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Basic understanding of database i.e MongoDB, MySQL databases is a plus</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Good understanding of </span><strong>Object-oriented</strong><span style="color:black"> programming</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Basic understanding in version control systems e.g. Git</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Basic understanding in Linux operating system</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Basic understanding of cloud services – Azure, AWS, etc</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Basic understanding of Devops</span></li><li><span style="color:black">A degree in Computer Science or equivalent industry experience</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Passionate with building elegant, scalable software that solves practical problems</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Team player and can do attitude</span></li><li><span style="color:black">Good problem solving skills and attention to detail</span></li></ul></div></span></div>
```

But when I change it to return `jd.text`, here's what came out:

```
'Job Responsibilities:Provide innovative solutions to complex business problemsPlan, develop and implement large-scale projects from conception to completionDevelop and architect lifecycle of projects working on different technologies and platformsDesign, develop and implement new integrationJob Requirements:Proficient in Java and preferably in Python as wellBasic understanding of database i.e MongoDB, MySQL databases is a plusGood understanding of\xa0Object-oriented\xa0programmingBasic understanding in version control systems e.g. GitBasic understanding in Linux operating systemBasic understanding of cloud services – Azure, AWS, etcBasic understanding of DevopsA degree in Computer Science or equivalent industry experiencePassionate with building elegant, scalable software that solves practical problemsTeam player and can do attitudeGood problem solving skills and attention to detail'
```

So I have two problems here:

1. Lists aren't converted correctly.
2. Formatted text (the word **Object-oriented** in this case) isn't parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method with adding a space as the `separator=` argument, in order to "un-nest" the text.

So, instead of:

```
return jd.text
```

use:

```
return jd.get_text(separator=" ")
```

you can also use:

```
jd.get_text(separator="\n")
```

to get the text outputted on separate lines.

*(Note: I couldn't reproduce your second problem, but see if this solved it).*

Comment: Thanks, the `get_text()` method solved it. As for the second issue, I found the solution elsewhere, using `unicodedata.normalize()`